# Is there an standard class for Events in Java?

Tags: java

I wrote a Listener. Now I want to notify it, when a change occurs. Nothing special.

Now I'm asking myself: 
Is there I standard class for Events that I can use, or do I have to write a new one by myself?

I know there ara java.awt.Event and AWTEvent. But I am not working directly at GUI level here. Furthermore we are using Swing at GUI level. So I'm not shure if it is a good idea to mix Swing and AWT.

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its ancient and simple, but you could use Observer/Obserable in java.util:

> java.util
>
> public class Observable extends Object
>
> This class represents an observable
>   object, or "data" in the model-view
>   paradigm. It can be subclassed to
>   represent an object that the
>   application wants to have observed.
>
> An observable object can have one or
>   more observers. An observer may be any
>   object that implements interface
>   Observer. After an observable instance
>   changes, an application calling the
>   Observable's notifyObservers method
>   causes all of its observers to be
>   notified of the change by a call to
>   their update method.

For more info, try http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-1996/jw-10-howto.html.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing special about events in Java. If your events are not GUI events, then it would be less confusing for you to use your own class and not mix them with `java.awt.Events`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using swing, you can take a look at [EventBus](https://eventbus.dev.java.net/):

> The Event Bus is a single-process publish/subscribe event routing library, with Swing extensions. The EventBus is fully-functional, with very good API documentation and test coverage (80+%). It has been deployed in many production environments, including financial, engineering and scientific applications.

Answer (score 2):

I've always used [EventObject](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html) as the base class for my custom events.  Here's what the JavaDoc says:

> The root class from which all event state objects shall be derived.
>
> All Events are constructed with a
>   reference to the object, the "source",
>   that is logically deemed to be the
>   object upon which the Event in
>   question initially occurred upon.

Comment: +1, and be careful rolling your own events.  If you can, follow the way other Java libraries do it as closely as possible.  When something is Serializable, make your corresponding object Serializable, etc.  Use the same naming patterns and methods wherever you can. Working with hand-rolled events can be obnoxious under some circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a standard solution in Swing apps is to maintain a list of event listeners in the class the event originates from. When the event occurs you iterate over the list and notify each listener of the event. So it can be something like this (I omitted the access modifiers and some of the type declarations for brevity):

```
class SomeClassInWhichTheEventOccurs {
    List<MyListener> listeners;
    void addListener(listener) { listeners.add(listener); }
    void removeListener(listener) { listeners.remove(listener); }
    void fireEvent(someEventParameters) {
        foreach (listener in listeners) listener.eventOccured();
    }
    void someMethodInWhichTheEventOccurs() {
       ...
       fireEvent(someEventParameters);
    }
}
```

The event parameters can be just anything: you can create your own event class, reuse java.awt.Event, or pass some parameters of arbitrary types.

Answer (score 0):

Swing is based upon AWT, so you have to mix it. The problem comes with mixing AWT heavyweight components with Swing lightweight components. Don't use AWT heavyweight components.

Just to be notified that something has changed `javax.swing.event.ChangeListener` is fine. In fact, so long as you are not using a library that assumes the beans model, you can ignore event classes and use a observer without an event object.